# How to retrieve info colors / brush from material class

Tags: vb.net, helix-3d-toolkit

Hy,
i've some trouble in getting color information from ModelUIElement3D class.
I'm developing a simple GUI for manipulate 3D objects and using HelixToolkit.Wpf
The question is understand which is the proper color when the user select something in the drawing.
From ModelUIElement3D class you can retrieve GEOMETRYMODEL3D and MATERIAL.
I tryed to bypass the problem comparing directly material generate from the class MATERIALS.
But i'm stuck because the Visualstudio doesn't allow me to compare:

```
If model.Material = Materials.Blue Then
End If
```

The error is : "=" equal isn't allowed for material class.

I've tryied also to set a name to material:

```
model.Material.SetName("Blue")
```

It give me an error saying that name material property is readonly.
Any other advice???
Thanks!
Miller

Answer (score 0):

When you use a single equals sign, it is interpreted as an "assignment" rather than a "comparison."

Try this instead:

```
if (model.Material == Materials.Blue)
{ ... }
```

Take a look at the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/dd183752.aspx#Anchor_1), where you can also read more about equality comparisons in C#.